# how to add image button left and right side of table layout?

Tags: android

i need to add two image button on left and right side of table layout  this is my screen

[image: current screen]

i want to make screen like this

[image: desired screen]

adding two image button left and right side of table layout ho to add this button?? help me please

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/lightgray"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:height="60sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/last_week"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/meenu" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/last_month"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
   </ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_today"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_month"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageButton>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_week"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>






 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6">


    <TableRow
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:background="#FEE5AC"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sunday"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/monday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tuesday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/wednesday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thur"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fri"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/friday"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/saturday"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">



 <Button
    android:id="@+id/e00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" >
 </Button>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/e01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="#000000" >
 </Button>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/e02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="#000000" >
 </Button>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/e03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
 </Button>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/e04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" >
 </Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="#000000" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" >
</Button>

    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>








</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your table layout in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and use layout weights to have the table take up all remaining space after accounting for the button widths:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton . . . (left image button attributes) />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" . . . >
        . . .
    </TableLayout>
    <ImageButton . . . (right image button attributes) />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what u mean by <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

Comment: in my code there is no linearlayout above Tablelayout? only single one at the start of xml file   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: @user2619496 - Do these steps: 1) add a new `LinearLayout`, with horizontal orientation, around the current `TableLayout`; 2) add two `ImageButton` elements, one on either side of the `TableLayout`, with appropriate attributes; 3) change the `android:layout_width` attribute for the `TableLayout` to `"0dp"` and add a new `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute. That's it.